Chart.js 3.9.1 throws cannot read property of undefined reading prototype error in react
I am using React 16 and try to implement a sankey chart visualization with Chart.js.
Since Chart.js v4 requires Webpack 5 or some other Babel magic that I cannot really change in my clusterf**k of a project, I downgraded to v3.9.1 and now I am encountering the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') .
This is my component code
import { Chart as ChartJS, registerables } from "chart.js";
import { SankeyController, Flow } from "chartjs-chart-sankey";
import React, { useState} from "react";
import "./SankeyChart.css";
import { Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";

interface SankeyChartProps {
  config: any;
}

ChartJS.register(SankeyController, Flow);

export const SankeyChart = (props:SankeyChartProps) => {

  const [colors,setColors] = useState({
    Oil: "#000000",
    Coal: "gray",
    "Fossil Fuels": "slategray",
    Electricity: "blue",
    Energy: "orange",
  })
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState({
    Oil: 1,
    "Natural Gas": 2,
    Coal: 3,
    "Fossil Fuels": 1,
    Electricity: 2,
    Energy: 1,
  })
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState({
    Oil: "black gold (label changed)",
  })
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          { from: "Oil", to: "Fossil Fuels", flow: 15 },
          { from: "Natural Gas", to: "Fossil Fuels", flow: 20 },
          { from: "Coal", to: "Fossil Fuels", flow: 25 },
          { from: "Coal", to: "Electricity", flow: 25 },
          { from: "Fossil Fuels", to: "Energy", flow: 60 },
          { from: "Electricity", to: "Energy", flow: 25 },
        ],
        priority,
        labels,
        colorFrom: (c) => getColor(c.dataset.data[c.dataIndex].from),
        colorTo: (c) => getColor(c.dataset.data[c.dataIndex].to),
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "black",
      },
    ],})
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function (context) {
            const { from, to, flow } = context.raw;
            return `${from} → ${to}: ${flow}`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  
  
  function getColor(name)
  {
    return colors[name] || "green"
  }
  return <Chart type="sankey" data={data} options={options}/>
};

The error happens in the ChartJS.register line.
Another thread said that you need to load it lazily which I did with the component in its parent but it did not help. I also set up a test project that contained the exact same code and that worked.

What do you mean by "I also set up a test project that contained the exact same code and that worked."?

It means I set up a new react project that contained just the one component and it worked

Does that mean that the code you have posted works and the error is somewhere else in the first project? Maybe you could make a stackblitz or codesandbox that shows the error.
